# When uploading a picture with carrierwave and dropzone, render a thumbnail version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Im using carrierwave and dropzone to upload some pictures to a album.

Everything is working fine, except that, when I add a new picture to the album, it re-renders the file without the thumbnail size.

My controller is like this:

```
class MediaContentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @media_contents = Media.all
  end

  def create
    @media = Media.new(file_name: params[:file])
    @album = Album.find(params[:album])
    @media.album = @album
    if @media.save!
      render json: @media
    else
      render json: { error: 'Failed to process' }, status: 422
    end
  end
end


class MediaUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
   end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<% if media_contents.empty? %>
  <h5 id="no-media">No Media Found</h5>
<% else %>
  <% media_contents.each do |media| %>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag media.file_name_url(:thumb) %>
        <div class="caption">
          <p>
            <%= check_box_tag 'media_contents[]', media.id %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, in my view the image is being shown in full size (not in thumbnail). I suspect about this line:

```
 render json: @media
```

I already try to do

```
render json: @media.file_name_url(:thumb)
```

But If I do this it doesnt show nothing at all.

Any help?

Comment: can you show the full view where `media_contents` is defined?Also, is it `show` view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have gone through the below tutorial

[Image uploading using carrierwave](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/rails-image-upload-using-carrierwave-in-a-rails-app--cms-25183)

That does work for me just try to change your view some thing like that

```
<% if media_contents.empty? %>
  <h5 id="no-media">No Media Found</h5>
<% else %>
  <% media_contents.each do |media| %>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag media.thumb.url %>
        <div class="caption">
          <p>
            <%= check_box_tag 'media_contents[]', media.id %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Didnt work. After upload my image, on the preview it comes with the normal size. I too followed this tutorial